# MATLAB: color scale with probplot

Tags: matlab, plot, probability, colormap

I have two 1D vectors of the same length, `data` and `my_parameter`. I use `probplot` to see the probability plot for data, as follows:

```
h = probplot(gca, data);
%  in next line, want color based on my_parameter, not static color as used.
set(h, 'color', [0.5 0.5 0.5]);
set(h, 'marker', '.');
```

I would like to color by `my_parameter`, the goal being to see whether certain values of `my_parameter` throw off the normality of the distribution. Is there a way to use a color scale, e.g., `parula`, in conjunction with the probplot function?

I have tried:

- Replacing the `[0.5 0.5 0.5]` with `'parula'`.
- Replacing the `[0.5 0.5 0.5]` with `parula`.
- Replacing the `[0.5 0.5 0.5]` with a m-row 3-column double matrix, where each row has the rgb values that `parula` would map `my_parameter` to. (So m is the length of `my_parameter`.)
- Getting rid of the line `set(h, 'color', [0.5 0.5 0.5]);`, and adding a line `colormap(parula);` below the set lines.

If there is not a way to do this using the `probplot` function directly because of how it is written (e.g. if it is written to accept only 3-element vectors), I guess I'll have to try to rewrite my own version of `probplot` using one of the `scatter` functions. I could dig around and figure this out, but before I start doing this, could anyone point me to a resource where this is done already perchance?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x=rand(1,15); % dummy data to plot
probplot(x)
h = probplot(gca,x);
c = parula(10);

% this changes the color of the 'x' marks to be the first row of the parula matrix
h(1).Color = c(1,:); 

% this changes the color of the dashed line to be the 9th row of the parula matrix
h(2).Color = c(9,:)
```

The above produces this:
[image]